# Do I need to update firmware with Intel® SSD Firmware Update Tool for intel 535 SSD when using Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: ssd, intel, firmware

Should I download and install it for better performance or better stability?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same one and I wanted to update, but it's already the latest firmware. You should update SSD firmware regardless of the OS; it does wonders for the drive and keeps its life-span stable, controls writing and reading, eliminates bugs and improves performance.

To upgrade it, use the Intel® SSD Firmware Update Tool, which is independent from the OS, from their website, but prior to that, check if your current SSD firmware version is the latest.

Use smartmontools:

> sudo apt-get install smartmontools

Then

> sudo smartctl -i /dev/sda

My firmware is R21, which is the latest according to the website:
https://downloadcenter.intel.com/download/18363/Intel-SSD-Firmware-Update-Tool

Comment: Do I need to enable the TRIM or something else on Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Could you please open a [new question](/questions/ask) if you have a new or follow-up question? The comment section is not suitable or meant for new questions or extended discussion.

Comment: I'm not sure, but I've read somewhere that Intel SSD-s are high quality and do not actually need that but I will look into it.